# Azure API Apps removing standard server headers

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-api-apps

I have a ASP.net WebApi deployed to azure using API Apps. To check another item off the mystical list that is best practice, I would like to remove standard server headers from all HTTP requests (x-powered-by, server, x-aspnet-version). My web.config is below as per configuration suggested [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/removing-standard-server-headers-on-windows-azure-web-sites/)

If deploying my application to an Azure Web App, the headers are successfully removed. However, it appears repeating the same deployment to an Azure API APP does not respect the standard web.config configuration to do this and the headers above are still present on all http requests.

Does anyone know if this is just not supported yet, or if there is an alternative way of doing this? I can only but think the gateway, or other, device is not respecting the removal.

```html
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false"  />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true"></requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

We are looking into this and will get it fixed.  In the meantime, you may be able to go to the app setting for the gateway and modify its web.config.  Steps:

1. Navigate to YOURGATEWAYNAME.scm.azurewebsites.net
2. Navigate to site\wwwroot
3. Scroll to web.config and click the edit button to the left.  You will be able to edit this file.

Alternatively, if you are not using any of the API Apps specific features, you can deploy your Web API as a Web App.

Comment: Hi @Mohit I gave this a try, editing the web.config of the gateway to be the same as that posted above via KUDO, however the standard headers are still present when viewing requests via Fiddler. I do plan on using some of the specific API app features, hence if at all possible I am trying to get this to work with API Apps instead of web apps.